# How to delete last row in output file generated by nzsql

Tags: sql, unix

I am trying to delete last row in the file generated by nzsql.Please find the below query.

```
nzsql -A  -c "SELECT * FROM AM_MAS_DIVISION_DIM" > abc.out
```

When I execute this query the output will be generated and stored in abc.out.This will include both header columns as well as some time information at the bottom.But I don't need the bottom metadata and want to keep only my header columns. How can I do this using only nzsql.Please help me.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just pipe the output to a unix command to remove it?  I think something like this will work:

```
nzsql -A  -c "SELECT * FROM AM_MAS_DIVISION_DIM" | sed '$d' > abc.out
```

Seems to be a recommended solution for getting rid of the last line (although ed, gawk, and other tools can handle it).

Answer (score 2):

use -r flag in the nzsql command to avoid getting that row [assuming the metadata referred in question is the row count summary line, ex: (3 rows)]

-r  Suppresses the row count that is displayed at the end of the SQL output.

reference: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/ntz/v7r0m3/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.nz.adm.doc%2Fr_sysadm_nzsql_command.html